# Remove three dot of applicationbar in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

see the application bar in WP7, for example this one :  [image]

You have the + icon and the - icon. On the right, there's three dot ...

How can I remove them (I found them ugly) and the fonctionnaly ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3 dots are a button, they hide/show the menu items on the bottom of the AppBar.

Comment: They also show the labels on the buttons too - they can't be removed either - you can adjust the opacity of the main app bar but the dots, labels and any appbar buttons remain.

Comment: If I have no menu items, and don't want to show the labels, and use only the buttons ...
not possible ?

Comment: Not possible, and would be a usability nightmare

Comment: Ok, I have maybe not understood the power of the application bar. For example, in the image, for me, it would be acceptable to only have a bar that has the + and - Button. Like a "file" menu

Comment: In the image above you removed the labels, which isn't a good thing, now those buttons have no context to what they mean. Also you HAVE menu items there, which are being shown.

Comment: This image was an example, if you look at this one http://dotneteers.net/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/vbandi/image_5F00_1FD167FD.png they are self explainatory ...  and there's NO dot ...

Comment: I would imagine that image is from a pre-release version of the OS, things like that change a lot as they get closer to production. Also I feel like the AppBar is quite half-baked, its missing a lot of things that are really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

One option which I think was added in Mango is to set the Mode of the ApplicationBar to ApplicationBarMode.Minimized. The dots will still be there, but the bar will take 32 pixels instead of 72 pixels from the bottom of the screen.